# Button can't forward me to next page

Tags: c#, datareader

Following is the code for the button but when I click the button, it does not forward me to the desired page. 
Is there something wrong with my `DataReader` loop?

```
{
    SqlConnection connBadge = new SqlConnection("Data Source =localhost;" +
                       "Initial Catalog = BreastCancer; Integrated Security = SSPI");
    connBadge.Open();

    SqlCommand cmdfBadge = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE pid=1", connBadge);
    SqlDataReader dr;

    dr = cmdfBadge.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        String pName = dr["pName"].ToString();
        String pPrice = dr["pPrice"].ToString();

        int b = Convert.ToInt16(pPrice);
        int a = Convert.ToInt16(ddQty1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        int g = a * b;

        String Badge = "INSERT into Cart (Name,Price,Quantity,gPrice) Values('" + pName + "', '" + b + "', '" + a + "','" + g + "')";

        SqlCommand cmdBadge = new SqlCommand(Badge, connBadge);

        cmdBadge.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    dr.Close();
    connBadge.Close();

    Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");        
}
```

Comment: just a general remark, the use of "using" is recommended in your connection, and datareader (ie. using(SqlDataReader dr = cmdfBadge.ExecuteReader()) { /* content */ }

Comment: Your code doesn't show *anything* to do with paging. (And you should use `using` statements instead of calling Close explicitly, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: may be the page with the button is the same as cart.aspx

Comment: is   Cart.aspx in a separate folder or any error message displaying?

Comment: No error message, it is in the same folder.
response.redirect changes the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter and try sqldata adapter:

```
{
    SqlConnection connBadge = new SqlConnection("Data Source =localhost;" +
                       "Initial Catalog = BreastCancer; Integrated Security = SSPI");
    connBadge.Open();

    SqlCommand cmdfBadge = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE pid='1'", connBadge);

    var dSet = new DataSet();
    var dt = new Datatable();
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdfBadge);

    da.Fill(dSet);
    dt = dSet.Tables[0];

    foreach(Datarow a in dt.Rows)
    {
        String pName = a["pName"].ToString();
        String pPrice = a["pPrice"].ToString();

        int b = Convert.ToInt16(pPrice);
        int a = Convert.ToInt16(ddQty1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        int g = a * b;

        String Badge = "INSERT into Cart (Name,Price,Quantity,gPrice) Values(@Name,@Price,@Quantity,@gPrice)";

        SqlCommand cmdBadge = new SqlCommand(Badge, connBadge);

        sqlCommand.Addwithvalue("@Name",pName);
        sqlCommand.Addwithvalue("@Price",b)
        sqlCommand.Addwithvalue("@Quantity",a)
        sqlCommand.Addwithvalue("@gPrice",g)
        cmdBadge.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }            

    connBadge.Close();

    Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
}
```

Regards

Comment: what's the directive needed to use datatable?

Comment: @Kenneth, `System.Data.DataTable` (using `System.Data`)

Comment: ha, this is even better than what I've said. I reccon the AddWithValue method has automatic type conversion to sql-types?

Comment: Yeah..or if he wants to to be specific of course he can use command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pName;

Comment: what do you mean using system.data?
not very good at this sorry. i've typed in using system.data but the thing didn't work, so i tried using system.data.datatable and they said its a namespace so i can't use using

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code with a try/catch statement to see if any exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your insert statement, I believe it will fail if the datatypes of your price, quantity and gprice are of type integer:

```
String Badge = "INSERT into Cart (Name,Price,Quantity,gPrice) Values('" + pName + "', '" + b + "', '" + a + "','" + g + "')";
```

You should not wrap these in quotes, remove the quotes and try again.

```
String Badge = "INSERT into Cart (Name,Price,Quantity,gPrice) Values('" + pName + "', " + b + ", " + a + "," + g + ")";
```

Try to use descriptive variable names, the using statement and a try-catch statement,  in the future.